# How to set these four buttons in one line even if app runs on any screen size?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-button

I tried this code but text on these buttons are messed in my phone; although it is fine in Nexus 5 emulator....! How can I put these 4 buttons one line dynamically so that they can look same on any screen size...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:weightSum="8" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bback"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bforward"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Forward" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/brefresh"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Refresh" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bclear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Clear History" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using width as wrap_content may solve your problem. You will have to remove weights then.

Comment: but then button sizes will become different...:(

Comment: do you  want to keep the button size as same in any screen size ?

Comment: So if you are willing to have same sizes than using weigth=1 and width=wrap_content is best way to do it.In this case it may happen that your text may move in two lines

Comment: yes DavidJhons but text should adjust accordingly

Comment: you cant adjust the textsize if you keep the button size as it is. If so, you need to adjust the button size according to the screen. According to my answer , button size and text size will be remain as it is. If you need to adjust the textsize with the screen, you have to let the button size increase accordingly. In such case remove the inner linear layout and set layout properties to button.

Answer (score 3):

set `android:layout_width` to `0dp` instead of `fill_parent` for all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will keep the button size as same in any device , also spread the buttons with equal distance on any device,

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bback"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="Back"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>

            //same as layout 2,3,4 and respective button with in it


        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITTEED**
**Please try with this:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bback"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bforward"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Forward" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/brefresh"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Refresh" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bclear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Clear History" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```